Can fault tolerant computation be performed in $1$d with strictly local gates?
I have been under the impression that fault-tolerant universal quantum computation with nonvanishing thresholds requires at least two-dimensional connectivity of gates, not merely one-dimensional connectivity. However, this 1999 paper by Gottesman seems to challenge my belief.
Am I interpreting this correctly? If I lay out qubits on a line and I'm only allowed to perform faulty nearest-neighbor and next-nearest gates and local measurements of ancillas, can I perform universal quantum computation fault-tolerantly with a nonvanishing threshold?

I am still trying to understand the details of the construction.
In particular, I believe Gottesman argues that repeatedly concatenating a quantum error correcting code can nevertheless be done through local measurements of ancillas, many SWAP gates, and nearest-neighbor and next-nearest-neighbor gates along a line. To my understanding, the number of qubits are exponentially growing with the number of levels of concatenation, causing exponentially growing time delays when slowly shuffling qubits to measure stabilizer at a given level of concatenation. However, despite this, the recursive formulas for error rate at a given level of concatenation still give rise to a threshold.

The paper "Logical Qubit in a Linear Array of Semiconductor Quantum Dots" has a construction of a fault tolerant code with a threshold using nearest neighbor interactions on a 1d line of qubits.




+1 Thanks! I think I might have a gap in my knowledge of fault tolerance. It seems they only do error detection. Is that really enough to get a threshold theorem saying that $poly(n)$ gates on $n$ qubits can be simulated with arbitrarily low error up to multiplicative polylog overhead? (Maybe I should make that a separate question!)

@user196574 they say error correction in the abstract

You're right. I saw they did a bunch of distance-2 codes, but I jumped to conclusions, my bad! They also have distance-3 codes.

Also, note to myself: I shouldn't have been so quick dismiss distance-2 codes; concatenating them allows for correction, not just detection; see https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.80.022313 for example of concatenating $[[4,1,2]]$ codes in 1d.
